# Git conflicts on master when policies in VSTS

Tags: git, version-control, merge, azure-pipelines

I have 2 problems when initiating a pull request on a git based VSTS repository.

1. We have a master, develop and a number of feature branches. We create feature branches from develop. We merge feature branches into the develop branch using a pull request, then once in a while we init a pull request from develop to master. We get conflicts on master if a file has ever been edited (and so, was merged to master) before. It looks like it's keeping track of every file, but we just want to have develop overwrite master.
2. Previously we could solve these conflicts by just getting the master, then merge master in develop and push using our original develop files. Because we have branch policies and because of recent "feature" changes of VSTS, we are not allowed to do a push directly on a branch. You cannot toggle this feature (even if you don't use other policies).

[image: cannot directly push into develop by policy]

[image: cannot push to develop branch]

I use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to do most of the git operations.

So is there anything I can do to get develop to master? Why am I always getting conflicts on the master branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is still there, but that is just how it currently works on VSTS.

The second problem has been solved, and therefor we don't need to solve the first problem anymore because we don't have any conflicts anymore on master.
As said before there was never a direct check-in on master but we did squash merge on all of our branches. So from a feature branch to develop, but also from develop to master.

In order not to have conflicts, we use the following policies:

- We force squash merge from feature-branch to develop branch

[image]

- We force No-fast-forward merge from develop to master branch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your fist problem, it is hard to determine the exact cause for the conflict without reviewing your commit history. I'm going to take a wild guess and say that isn't an option. What I can tell you from personal experience that is the likely issue, make sure you don't have people merging a feature branch or hot fix branch directly into `master`, skipping your `develop` branch all together. This will cause conflicts when you are trying to merge. Also, make sure people can't commit directly to your `master` branch (that should be protect as well).

As for your second issue, you can't un-check `Protect this branch` because you still have the `Check for linked work items` checked. If you un-check that first, you will be able to un-check the branch being protected.

Comment: As I explained before, even if I uncheck everything, the Protect branch option is still checked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set branch policy on `develop` branch, it’s not a good choice to merge `master` into `develop` and push to `develop` branch (git will also stop you to do that as the screen shot you showed).

The easier way to overwrite `master` branch with `develop` is that **merge `develop` into `master` with merge strategies by git command line**.

Details as below:

**1.Click Terminal in SourceTree.**

[image]

**2.Then use below commands:**

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge develop -X theirs
git push origin master
```

Now your `master` branch is overwrite by `develop` branch.

> Why am I always getting conflicts on the master branch?

When you try to merge `develop` into `master`, if there has conflicts, that means you modified the same file(s) both on `develop` and `master` branch. So git will show the conflict files (with same filename but different contents). And if you `-X theirs` option for `git merge develop` command, it will resolve the conflicts automatically by keeping the version from `develop` branch.

Comment: I don't get it why we cannot use branch policies on develop branch. We want to make sure users check in with a linked work item. We want the build to complete after a feature branch PR. Of course when there are no policies on develop, I can still merge master to develop. But we never check-in directly to master so I don't know why we get conflicts.

Comment: Even you added develop with branch policy to link work item, VSTS will protect your develop branch for: **Code changes must be submitted via pull request** and **This branch cannot be deleted** (you can find in the top of Policies Tab). So you must add changes via PR. If you don't push changes to `master` directly, please pull changes on `master` branch, and view the history graph and you can also add the graph in your question yo make it clearly.